# Why did Agent H and Riza break up with each other?

Tags: men-in-black, men-in-black-international

When Agent H fell for Riza, he didn't know that she was a criminal and as a matter of fact one of the biggest criminals of the galaxy. Did this fact break this relationship? I am skeptical about this because Agent H had friendship with Riza's guards, but non-criminals can also have guards so this doesn't prove that he continued to remain in the relationship after knowing that she was a criminal.

In the beginning of the movie, we also saw Agent H sleeping with an alien with octopus type hand tentacles which left pink marks on Agent H's body. Did this cause the break up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MiB: International novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/43778563-men-in-black-international) (or rather the short prequel story *Open Arms* found at the end of said novel), H broke up with Riza for the same reason that all cop/baddie summer romances fail, because in the final analysis, he's still a cop and she's still a baddie.

H met her while he was trying to infiltrate her criminal organisation and meet with what he thought was her father. Unbeknownst to H, Riza had killed her father and taken over his business. She and H had a brief fling before she found proof that he was MiB and presumably sent to find and kill her.

> “So, I guess you were waiting a few more dates before telling me anything about all this?” Guns pointed at him from every conceivable direction.
>   “Don’t even.” There was anger in her eyes. “I found your neuralyzer in your room. When were you going to come clean and tell me you were MiB?”

From that point onwards, their relationship was basically over, ended by mutual (albeit sad) consent.

> “I never lied about how you made me feel.” H didn’t hide the pain in his eyes. For a moment, Riza’s ice queen act disappeared, and H saw how much this was hurting her too. He hated what had to come next, but this was his only chance.

Comment: "That psycho bitch is gonna slit his throat." ~> I thought that H was the one who ended the relationship or he was at the fault of cheating.